Ubuntu 24.04 Meteor Lake, no sound
so in my case, everything seems fine, but when I try to play some sound
it shows gauge on test speaker screen, as if it is playing, but no sound comes
from speaker...
Below is my aplay -l info:
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 4: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 5: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 31: Deepbuffer HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

I have tried reinstalling pipewire, everything seems to be in order, and sound plays if I plug in external usb sound card... Via that card, but not via built in one...

Update I tried blacklisting  sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl in alsa, but I get the same thing.

Can you share more details about your hardware (laptop model/sound card details, if you know it)?

Is this enough: cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [sofhdadsp      ]: sof-hda-dsp - sof-hda-dsp
HP-HPEnvyx3602_in_1Laptop16_ac0xxx-Type1ProductConfigId-8C66

Please edit the question and add this information. Is the laptop model HP Envy x3602?

Ok, so I was able to fix this by switching to newer kernel, there
are several steps.

Make sure that secure boot is off (you need to enter in bios,
and it's under boot options), you can test it with this command:
mokutil --sb-state

install tool called mainline https://github.com/bkw777/mainline

type mainline list to list available kernels

install latest kernel.

reboot


You can see your kernel version typing uname -r
In my case, sound wasn't working with 6.8 kernel but works with 6.12
